# How to handle collections.FreqItemset from FPGrowth with PySpark?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I am using FPGrowth from pyspark MLlib, the output of this function is type `collections.FreqItemset`, which I am not really familiar and I am finding a hard time to use and I do not find much documentation or examples. **This is my questions, is there any way to use this format in Python 3? how to use handle it? where this format come from?**
Because I do not really know much about how to handle this on Python 3 I try I try to convert this into something I am more familiar with, for example pandas dataframe. However I think this is a kind of dirty. So I leave here my temporal solution waiting for some insights from you guys.

Taking pretty much the example in the documentation to use FPGRowth for python, which is [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html).

To set up the environment in pyspark

```
import pyspark
sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
```

To run the function in a example and see results:

```
from pyspark.mllib.fpm import FPGrowth

data = sc.textFile("sample_fpgrowth.txt")
transactions = data.map(lambda line: line.strip().split(' '))
model = FPGrowth.train(transactions, minSupport=0.2, numPartitions=10)
result = model.freqItemsets().collect()
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

If you do not find the file for the example, you can get it [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/data/mllib/sample_fpgrowth.txt).
The output is something like this[image]

Here is this guy: type `collections.FreqItemse` I have not idea how to handle properly in Python.

So the dirty way I am currectly using to transform it into pandas dataframe is this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = [0]) 
for fi in result:
    df.loc[''.join(str(e)+' ' for e in fi.items)[0:-1]] = int(fi.freq)
df.head()
```

What will output this:

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there.
Instead of using

```
for fi in result:
    print(fi)
```

Use this

```
for fi in result:
    print (''.join(fi['items']),fi['freq'])
```

or this

```
for items,frequency in result:
    print (''.join(items),frequency)
```

Here the items is a simple python list, and frequency should be an integer. It might not print as pretty as a pandas dataframe, but I am guessing what you want is to gain access to the values.